# Length of the longest side of a triangle given all angles and the sum of the length of the shorter edges

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let's say we have an arbitrary triangle were $c$ refers to the longest edge of the triangle while $a$ and $b$ refer to the 2 remaining shorter edges:

[image]

Given all angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and the sum of the length of the 2 shorter edges $d=a+b$ is it possible to calculate the length of $c$?

I feel like this should definitely be possible but no matter what theorem I throw at it, it always seems to result in needing to know the length of either $a$ or $b$, but only the length of the sum $d=a+b$ is known.

Comment: Ah, because $\alpha, \beta$ are also given, which makes it unique. I constructed the triangle only from just $a, b, \gamma$.

Comment: Extend side $b$ (at $\gamma$'s side) of a segment of length $a$. You get $$(a+b) \sin \frac{\gamma}2= c\sin\left(\beta +\frac{\gamma}2\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Simply use the law of sines to represent one of the shorter side lengths in terms of the other and a ratio of sines of the smallest two angles.

Comment: But then I'd still need the length of one of the shorter sides?